# Division Algorithm and Polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

By the Division Algorithm, I know I can reduce every polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ to a polynomial $ax+b$ mod $x^2+1$. 
There are two possibilities for $a$ and two for $b$, a total of 4.
 It follows that $\mathbb Z_{2}[x]/(x^{2}+1)$
is a field with
4 elements. 
This is where I continually keep getting stuck. I know two of the elements should be 0,1 but I don't know how to find all of the elements.

Comment: Other than $0$ and $1$ : There is the element $x$ , and the element $x+1$. Actually, your ring is NOT a field: $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x +1$, so if $2 =0$, the middle terms goes away, leaving $x^2 +1$, which is $\equiv 0\pmod {x^2+1}$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ is not a field since $(x+1)(x+1) = x^2 + 1$. It is not even an integral domain.

Comment: Wow. Just saw peter's comment. My apologies for the duplicate. Damn mobile app...

Answer (score 1):

$x, x+1,1,0$ are the solutions

Comment: how did you find that?

Comment: See that you solved it ;). The solutions are $p(x)=ax+b$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_2$